# Can't connect to archive.canonical.com

Tags: apt

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 and I cannot connect to `archive.canonical.com`. Is it normal?

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                            
Ign:3 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease                                                    
Hit:4 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release                                                      
Hit:5 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                                    
Hit:6 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial InRelease                                                             
Hit:7 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease                                                            
Hit:9 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x zesty InRelease                                                                    
Hit:10 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                
0% [Connecting to archive.canonical.com (2001:67c:1360:8c01::16)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1562::16)] [Connecting to dl.google.com (2a00:1450:400e:802::200e)]
```